# How to display the input port(left dot) of a self-defined node in nodered?

Tags: node-red

I define a node in nodered myself which is like the following one.
[image]

But, I do not know how to program to make the right node look exactly like the left one(its left edge have a dot(input port) too). Following is union.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
RED.nodes.registerType('Union', {
    category: 'Aggregation',
    color: '#8192d6',
    defaults: {
        //type indication task
        env: { value: "spark" },
        parameter1: { value: "" },
        parameter2: { value: "" },
        output_1: { value: "" },

    },
    inputLabels: ["parameter1", "parameter2"],
    outputLabels: ["output_1"],

    inputs: 2,
    outputs: 1,
    icon: "file.png",
    label: function () {
        return this.name || "Union";
    }
 });
</script>

<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="Union">
    <div class="form-row">

    <label for="node-input-env"><i class="icon-tag"></i> 
environment</label><br>
        <select id="node-input-env">
            <option value="spark" selected>Spark</option>
        </select><br>

    <label for="node-input-parameter1"><i class="icon-tag"></i> parameter1</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="node-input-parameter1" placeholder="parameter1"><br>
    <label for="node-input-parameter2"><i class="icon-tag"></i> parameter2</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="node-input-parameter2" placeholder="parameter2"><br>
    <label for="node-input-output_1" style="width:160px;"><i class="icon-tag"></i> output_1</label>
    <input type="text" id="node-input-output_1" placeholder="output_1"> 
 <br>
 </div>
 </script>
 <script type="text/x-red" data-help-name="Union">A Not NULL aggregation node for data frame, you should specify Count condition</script>
```

Following is union.js.

```
module.exports = function (RED) {
function countNode(config) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
    var node = this;
    if (!config.condition) {
        this.warn('condition not specified.');
    }
  }
  RED.nodes.registerType('Union', countNode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You currently have `inputs: 2` in the node's html definition. The only valid values for the number of inputs is 0 or 1.